# Discord.js edit message after a reaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've just started with javascript trying to set up an discord bot with discord.js. I want to use this bot as an 'easy' way to organize raids. So people only need to klick on the Icon to sign in for the raid.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
```

... token, prefix etc.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
```

... some stuff for checking the command

```
message.channel.send('RaidID: ' + RaidID + '\nRaid: GOS \nRaid Leader: <@' + message.author.id + '> \nDate: ' + args[2] + '\nTime: ' + args[3]).then(messageReaction => {
                                            messageReaction.react('✅');
                                        });
```

so far the code works fine. It checks date and time just fine. Now I want to detect if someone have reacted to the message and mention him in the message by editing it. And I'm just not getting how to work with `awaitReactions`. Or if it even wokrs with `awaitReactions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your current message funtion

```
message.channel.send('RaidID: ' + RaidID + '\nRaid: GOS \nRaid Leader: <@' + message.author.id + '> \nDate: ' + args[2] + '\nTime: ' + args[3]).then(messageReaction => {
                                            messageReaction.react('✅');
                                        });
```

With this function:

```
message.channel
    .send(
        "RaidID: " +
            RaidID +
            "\nRaid: GOS \nRaid Leader: <@" +
            message.author.id +
            "> \nDate: " +
            args[2] +
            "\nTime: " +
            args[3]
    )
    .then((messageReaction) => {
        messageReaction.react("✅");
        messageReaction.awaitReactions((args, user) => {
            return !user.bot && args._emoji.name === "✅";

        }, { max: 1 }).then(reaction => {
            // SOMEONE REACTED
            console.log('REACTION');
        });
    });
```

It adds the `.awaitReactions` function in the `.then` of the promise. It checks whether the reaction is made by a user and the emoji ✅. In case of a correct reaction, the part at `// SOMEONE REACTED` is being called.

Comment: Thank you *-* I guess I'm understanding how it works. Even though it could only detect 1 reaction I could find the solution for detecting all 5 reactions I need to detect.